# Android - how to start foreground service on fragment?

Tags: android, service, fragment

I have a question about starting foreground service on fragment.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
PendingIntent pendingIndent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);  
Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_music, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());  
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, msg, pendingIndent);  
mNotification.flags = mNotification.flags|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;  
startForeground(1000, mNotification);
```

↑ I know this code makes start foreground service on Activity.

so I changed some code for use on fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), xxx.class);  
PendingIntent pendingIndent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 1, intent, 0);  
Notification noti = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_xxx, "xx", System.currentTimeMillis());  
noti.setLatestEventInfo(getActivity(), "title", "xx", pendingIndent);  
noti.flags = noti.flags|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;  
getActivity().startForeground(1000, noti);
```

and I got a problem with this :

```
getActivity().startForeground(1000, noti);
```

getActivity() doesn't have startForeground method and I want to start foreground service on fragment.

what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the `onStartCommand()` method of your service:

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, new Notification());
```

It might be that you need to return a `START_STICKY` that keeps the Service running until you call `selfStop()`.

Cheers!

Comment: @Downvoter: any reasons for down voting? Please tell us more.