# Cannot start foregrounf service form fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, foreground-service

I'm trying to start a foreground service from a fragment the service is started with the notification and all when I minimize the app the download still works but soon as I remove my apps from the recent the service is killed.

I have tried the solution as explained in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517746/android-how-to-start-foreground-service-on-fragment)

My service code:

```
public class VideoDownloadService extends Service {

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  //notification code with id 123
  startForeground(123,notification);

// my code to download video which works properly when the app is alive.
 stopSelf();
}

}
```

The service is registered in the manifest within the application tag:

```
<service android:name=".data.VideoDownloadService" />
```

This is how I start the service within my service as there is no `getActivity.startforegroundserivce` in fragments (only above api 26):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,VideoActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

But as soon as the app is removed from the recent screen the download is killed. Is this the intended behavior or am I missing something? Foreground services are not supposed to be tied to the app life cycle yes?

Comment: There're stopped as well, but restarted when you use `START_STICKY`. You should implement your download task in a separate thread, too. (Do you know about Android DownloadManager?). You can use it, instead of reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: no I want to download within the app data folder the files are supposed to be accessed by the app only. Downloadmanager keeps them in the open

Comment: hey a totally unrelated question I have the total file size in bytes current bytes downloaded how do I calculate the estimated time to complete the download. I am stumped with the math